# How to create horizontal tables in R (markdown)

Tags: r, html-table, r-markdown

I would like to present horizontal raw data tables for minimal datasets in R and R markdown. I havn't found a simple solution yet. Is there any table package that switches row and column by an easy default option?

````
---
title: "Horizontal Tables"
author: "Name"
date: "11 5 2021"
output: html_document
---

## Raw Data As Horizontal Table

```{r warning=FALSE, message=FALSE}
# raw data vertical
mydata <- data.frame(pass = (c(0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1)) ,
                     hours = c(2,1,3,2,4,7,4,8))
mydata

# (subset) of raw data horizontal
library(tidyverse)
glimpse(mydata)

# What package shows nice horizontal raw data tables?
library(gt)
gt(mydata)
```
````

The output should be transposed, i.e. rows and columns changed. `glimpse()` is showing horizontal values by default, but it lacks a nice table design.

[image]

Comment: Hi, have you tried to use `t()` and then pass your table to `gt()`, `kable()` or `flextable()`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is an idea using `t()` to transpose your table.

The code below uses `knitr::kable()` and `kableExtra`, you will find more information [here](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/kableExtra/vignettes/awesome_table_in_html.html#Overview) to choose the style you prefer.
If you want it to be very small: `kable_styling(bootstrap_options = c("condensed"),full_width = F, position = "left")`

````
---
title: "Horizontal Tables"
output: html_document
---

## Raw Data As Horizontal Table

```{r warning=FALSE, message=FALSE}
# raw data vertical
mydata <- data.frame(pass = (c(0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1)) ,
                     hours = c(2,1,3,2,4,7,4,8))
mydata

library(knitr)
library(kableExtra)
as.data.frame(t(mydata)) %>% kable(col.names = NULL) %>% kable_styling()
```
````

Output:

[image]